# sql query works in mysql not php

Tags: php, mysql

My query works in mysql but reports an error in the sql query in php. Any clues?

```
$sql = 'SELECT interval , loads
        FROM profiles
        WHERE DATE_FORMAT( interval,  '%H:%i:%s' ) LIKE  "%00:15:00"';

mysql_select_db('loads');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
```

Comment: you need to use `"` around the `%H:%i:%s`, atm you've got a php error because your string is split in 2

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html check reserved keywords

Comment: Why can't people leave the credits to the one who posted the answer first? OGHaza! Instead people post answers after reading that to get the points. How cheap :-9

Comment: @arkascha I agree, should be voted up the first correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
$sql = "SELECT `interval` , `loads`
    FROM profiles
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT( `interval`,  '%H:%i:%s' ) LIKE  '%00:15:00'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT interval , loads profiles DATE_FORMAT( interval,  '%H:%i:%s' ) LIKE  "."%00:15:00";

mysql_select_db('loads');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo "<table><tr><td>Time</td><td>Load</td></tr>".
"<tr><td>{$row['interval']}  </td><td>{$row['load']}</td></tr></table> ";
}
```

check this is it working for you :-) please let me know

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'SELECT interval , loads FROM profiles
WHERE DATE_FORMAT( interval,  \'%H:%i:%s\' ) LIKE  \'%00:15:00\'';
```

It is better to escape strings whenever possible

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your $sql string.

The string start with `'` and end with `'`. Then you can not use any `'` inside the string unless you [escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) it.

To escape a character in PHP you have to put a `\` before the character you want to use.

Then you should write :

```
$sql = 'SELECT interval , loads
    FROM profiles
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT( interval,  \'%H:%i:%s\' ) LIKE  "%00:15:00"';
```